# Display the captured image in corresponding imageview in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager item which has a button to capture image and an imageview to display the captured image. Is it possible to display the captured image in the same viewpager item.

This is my viewpager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_main"
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:contentPadding="10dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/check_item"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text="New CheckBox" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:id="@+id/editText_comments"
                android:hint="Comments"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_modified"
                android:layout_below="@+id/check_item"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add Image"
                android:id="@+id/button_addImage"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText_comments"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_preview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_addImage"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Previous"
                android:id="@+id/button_previous"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText_comments"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="3dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView_preview2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/button_addImage"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next"
                android:id="@+id/button_next"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageView_preview2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView_preview2"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView_preview2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You may add screens of what you have and what you need to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You show image using `Picasso` library from file or path.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("image path").into(imageView);
```